# How to turn a list into a column in a csv?

Tags: python, list, csv

Currently I have a populated list

```
list =[a, b, c, d]
```

I want to convert the content of the list to a csvfile and have all of the elements of the list be one column. This is the current code I have:

```
with open('twitter3.csv', 'w+') as csvfile:
    writer = csv.writer(csvfile, dialect='excel')
    writer.writerow(list)
```

The outputted csv file contains the elements of the list but as the method implies, it has written all the contents within the first row.

I have tried making a for loop to write each `element + \n` but the `writerow` method has an issue with that (puts commas after each letter),  and there is no `writecolumn` method for a `csvwriter`.

Comment: Are there any other columns?

Comment: @ShadowRanger sorry about the late response. I do not have any other columns at the moment but likely will in the future. I have decided to just rely on pandas

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To perform this task I would use [`pandas`](https://pandas.pydata.org) package as follows:

```
import pandas as pd
l=["a","b","c","d"]
df=pd.DataFrame(l)
df.to_csv("twitter3.csv", index=False,header=False)
```

`pandas` is also great to read csv and even work with Excel files.

Comment: I think this is the way to go. It seems like csv library is just a chore to deal with. None of the suggested solutions worked besides this one!

Answer (score 1):

This is about the simplest way I can think of to do it:

```
import csv

my_list = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd']

with open('twitter3.csv', 'w', newline='') as csvfile:
    writer = csv.writer(csvfile, dialect='excel')
    writer.writerows(tuple(item) for item in my_list)
```

Note I changed the name of your list variable to `my_list` so it wouldn't conflict with the built-in `list` class.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this by joining the elements of your list into a single string with new line characters `'\n\r'` as the separators, then write the whole string to your file.

For example:

```
my_list = [a, b, c, d]

with open("twitter3.csv", "w+") as csvfile:
    to_write = "\n\r".join(my_list)
    csvfile.write(to_write)
```

(Also `'\n'` works)

Answer (score 0):

I put all the code in one place, so that can copy and test it out.

```
import csv

# Should not use 'list' as variable
lst =['a', 'b', 'c', 'd']

# newline='' prevent additional new lines in file
with open('twitter3.csv', 'w+', newline='') as csvfile:
  writer = csv.writer(csvfile, dialect='excel')
  for l in lst:
    writer.writerow(l)
```

Output `twitter3.csv` is then:

```
a
b
c
d
```